# Spring data rest with intermediate layer (service layer)

Tags: rest, spring-data

Spring data rest 2 will be released soon and it allows to expose repositories as restful endpoints directly. In my opinion, Spring data rest is a great framework for restful web service application as it increases productivity by removing certain boilerplate codes. I have developed a restful application which consists of 3 layers: controller layer, service layer and data access layer(repository), Service layer is responsible for calling one or more repositories within transaction scope but    I couldn't figure out how spring data rest address this design issue.

Comment: Why did you develop a Controller layer when SDR provides its own Servlet?

Comment: May me my explanation is not clear. The application that I have developed doesn't use Spring data rest. Recently I came across the SDR framework and I would want to know what can be achieved by using SDR.

Comment: Calling several repository methods within a request is very common. May I know how can this be achieved or SDR simply does't allow you to do that.

Comment: Got ya. SDR is designed around one repository/one http endpoint. You can use Application Events to do additional work (see the Restbucks example), or you could consider database triggers.